# Can I drive a Crystal Report in a standalone application with .NET objects?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to learn Crystal Reports (VS 2005, VB) and [per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140229/how-to-use-crystal-reports-without-a-tightly-linked-db-connection) I was trying to drive the report with my own data objects instead of through a DB connection.

I found [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227595(VS.80).aspx) and it looked promising as an answer to my question, but after diving in it only seems to apply to web development.

Am I out of luck in trying to power a Crystal Report with .NET objects in a standalone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227609%28VS.80%29.aspx), I think the report might have to be a strongly typed report. Where did it indicate it was only for the web?

Comment: In the previous section, "Creating the Stock Class," the last step said, "From the Build menu, click Build Website."

Comment: The example seems to be for a web site, but what's stopping you from trying it with your class? Is the option not available when adding a crystal report to a non-web application?

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer for your previous question.

[How to use Crystal Reports without a tightly-linked DB connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140229/how-to-use-crystal-reports-without-a-tightly-linked-db-connection/1157001#1157001)