# How can I use strongly typed lists as the datasoruce for a Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I currently have

```
Class A

property x as List (Of Class B)

End Class

Class B

' some other properties
End Class
```

When I create crystal report to use Class A as datasource the field explorer doe snot show property x?

Is it possible to use strongly typed lists with Crystal Report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about List, but you can use ArrayList instead. See my answer on this question:

[How to use Crystal Reports without a tightly-linked DB connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140229/how-to-use-crystal-reports-without-a-tightly-linked-db-connection/1157001#1157001)